# C# regex array of subexpressions?

Tags: c#, regex

To my surprise I haven't been able to find an answer or example of what should be a fairly common problem parsing text with regex.  I'm using native C# regex; not a third part assembly.

It's a problem of a nested list; for example say I have a text file that has a defined format but I want to structure it in a class (hypothetical example below):

```
Input Text
Name: Joe Smith
Occupation: Software Developer
Patent(s) Awarded: 3 award(s)
                   Light Bulb
                   Rollercoasters
                   NTFS
```

Desired Output is a Match that has something *like* the following:

```
MatchCollection.Groups["Name"].Value
MatchCollection.Groups["Occupation"].Value
MatchCollection.Groups["AwardCount"].Value

... and then some form of list for the individual patents...
e.g. MatchCollection.Groups["Award"][0].Value
e.g. MatchCollection.Groups["Award"][1].Value
e.g. MatchCollection.Groups["Award"][2].Value
          ... and so on ...
```

What's being done now is a first pass to get all the non-list info and treat the patent list as a single string; e.g.:

```
Name:\s+(?<Name>.+)\nOccupation:\s+(?<Occupation>.+)\nPatent\(s\) Awarded:\s+(?<AwardCount>\d+).*\n(?<AwardInfo>(?:.*\r\n)*)
```

... and then making a secondary pass on the patent list to create the enumerable list of patent strings.  It would be nice if there was the construct below to tell regex that you want this subexpression-term to get picked up ever time it occurs:

```
(?<AwardInfo>(?:.*\r\n)*)*
                         ^
                         Which would return a second list to the Match object.
```

Am I overlooking something simple to get output that gives me the ability to iterate through the individual patents? If not has anyone creatively solved this problem only using one regex?

Comment: This isn't a regular language so a single regular expression will not work.

Comment: By regular language do you mean that it's a two dimentional set of lists or are you suggesting that I can't create a natural language that expresses it?  If the former I believe I can quite easily.

Comment: It is not [context free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Deciding_whether_a_language_is_regular).

Comment: Looks like Rawling just proved you wrong Tyler.

Comment: C# and most other programming languages with regular expression support add non-standard features. Three, a language is not necessarily a regular language if it can be represented by one of these enhanced "regular languages". Depending on these enhancements affects portability of that "regular language". Four, in fact, @Rawling's answer is not full-proof, because the number of `AwardInfo` groups will not necessarily match the number provided for the number of patents awarded, which easily invalidates its status as a regular language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up your regular expression so that `<AwardInfo>` matches each line seperately - by moving the `*` outside the group (and trim the whitespace, and make the newline optional):

```
(?:\s*(?<AwardInfo>.*(?:\r\n)?))*
```

then you can use the [`Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) property on that group to get each different value that the group matched. For example,

```
MatchCollection[0].Groups["AwardInfo"].Captures[0] is "Light Bulb"
MatchCollection[0].Groups["AwardInfo"].Captures[1] is "Rollercoasters"
MatchCollection[0].Groups["AwardInfo"].Captures[2] is "NTFS"
```